# Is there any way to simulate recursion without implicit or explicit use of the stack ADT?

Tags: recursion, stack

Usually functional recursion is simulated using the call stack ,but is there any way to simulate recursion without using the stack ADT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes: one of the well-known approaches to implementing functional languages with first-class continuations is to heap allocate activation records, deallocation being handled by garbage collection. In this scheme call information is arranged in an immutable DAG, and a continuation has the particularly straightforward implementation of a pointer to an activation record.

Without the motivation of first-class continuations this arrangement isn't all that attractive for performance reasons.

Answer (score 1):

You can simulate a stack using an array, for example (not using the stack ADT) ... But if you want an implementation of recursion without using stacks at all - implicit, explicit, or self-defined, go through this link:
http://home.olympus.net/~7seas/recurse.html